# Can I retag questions to get a topic badge?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, retagging

This is just something I was wondering: I currently have 19 non-CW answers in [real-analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/real-analysis). Could I just go through my old answers looking for a question which involves real analysis but hasn't been so tagged, and retag it in order to get the bronze badge? (No, I wouldn't do this.)

Comment: @Glorfindel appreciate the retag ;)

Answer (score 11):

Yes, that would work; your [tag scores](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=tags) are recalculated [once every 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178114/295232) and they will be based on the current tags of the question. Those tag scores affect badges; you can even *lose* a tag badge when a tag is removed from a question you answered.

As you say, you should not add tags in order to obtain badges; like all edits, they should be made to improve the post. Having the right tags makes it easier to find a question, so if a real analysis question is incorrectly tagged as [number-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/number-theory), it's fine to retag it to [real-analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/real-analysis).